# IList - LINQ to filter and order by

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects, generic-list

I have the following test code to search a generic list:

```
public void DoSearch(string searchTerm)
{

IList<MyEntity> entities = GetCollectionOfEntities();

IList<MyEntity> results = entities.Where(d => d.Description.Contains(searchTerm)).ToList();

}
```

I want to pass an order by parameter (which would be a property of MyEntity) and of course order my results based on that. I understand LINQ uses OrderBy but do not understand how to order by a property of MyEntity.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just use a `Func<TSource,TKey>` to specify the property that you want to order by:

```
DoSearch("foo", e => e.SomeProperty);

// ...

public void DoSearch<TKey>(string searchTerm, Func<MyEntity, TKey> orderBy)
{
    IList<MyEntity> entities = GetCollectionOfEntities();

    IList<MyEntity> results = entities
                              .Where(e => e.Description.Contains(searchTerm))
                              .OrderBy(orderBy)
                              .ToList();

    // etc
}
```

Comment: Okay this is a good start but how would I go about passing this as a parameter so that my method signature would be public void DoSearch(string searchTerm, orderby)...?

Comment: Not at all or using Reflection (which is slow and probably not useful in general). The Func<> way is really the best way to go here imo. +1

Comment: Excellent. Cheers for the help.

Comment: @youwhut: You'd need to pass the `Func<S,K>` into the method itself. I've updated the answer to demonstrate.

Comment: @LukeH what's the reason to use `TKey`?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void DoSearch(string searchTerm, Func<MyEntity, PropertyType> selector)
    {

       IList<MyEntity> entities = GetCollectionOfEntities();

       IList<MyEntity> results = entities
                      .Where(d => d.Description.Contains(searchTerm))
                      .OrderBy(selector)
                      .ToList();

   }

   DoSearch("searchTerm", entity => entity.Property)
```

PropertyType is the type of the property you want to sort. Else you could make it Generic like this:

```
    public void DoSearch<TKey>(string searchTerm, Func<MyEntity, Tkey> selector)
```

And call it.